# simple java regular expression matching

Tags: java, regex

I need to match
"/en",
"/ja",
"/zh-cn"

I have written regular expression like this

```
String str = "/en";
if(str.matches(".[(en)(ja)(zh\\-cn)]$"))
   System.out.println(str);
```

this doesnt work.can somebody help here please

Comment: Ever seen this character in regexps -- `|`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following (using `pattA|pattB` you can match `pattA` **or** `pattB`):

```
"/(en|ja|zh-cn)"
```

or following if you want match other language code:

```
"/[-a-z]+"

"/[a-z]{2}(-[a-z]{2})?"
```

Comment: should there be a `-` before `a-z` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve, `-` can also be after the `a-z`. Without `-`, it will not match `zh-cn`.

Comment: I prefer to put `-` at the beginning of `[]`. If it is used in the middle, it should be escaped (`\-`) to match `-` literally.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to understand how character classes work. The character class you're using will match any one character of `(` or `e` or `n` or `)` or `j` or `a` or `z` or `h`, etc.

You'll need to use a group to do what you're trying to do:

```
str.matches("/(?:en|ja|zh-cn)$")
```

The `|` is indicates 'or' and I used a non-capture group `(?: ... )`. Use a capture group `( ... )` if you intend to use the "en", "ja" or "zh-cn" later on.